# Changing outputs on a textual menu that uses a switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, output

Using Java I have a system class that has different methods for displaying details of a computer system. I then have a test system class that calls these methods as a menu using a switch statement. If the user enters choice 1 or 2 then it displays some input that I have hard coded. But if they choose choice three then they are promoted to enter their own input.

How do I then get choice 1 and 2 to show their input instead of mine if they enter it in choice 3 and then enter choice 1 and 2 again?

I’m a complete newbie with this and I’m not sure how I would do this, I have researched online and in books and was thinking maybe an if else statement somewhere, but I could be wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's the code I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SystemTest_Y3881268 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create System_Y3881268 object and test methods
        System_Y3881268 s=new System_Y3881268("Lenovo", 
                "Ideacentre A340-24IWL", 2);
        s.setHardDisk(2);
        s.setMemory(128);
        s.setPurchaseCost(599);

        //Create textual menu
        int memorySize;
        double hardDiskSize;

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice;
        do 
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("***** Computer system menu *****");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Choice 1: Print System Details");
            System.out.println("Choice 2: Diagnose System");
            System.out.println("Choice 3: Set Details");
            System.out.println("Choice 4: Print System Properties");
            System.out.println("Choice 5: Quit the Program");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 - 5");
            System.out.println();
            choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            switch(choice) 
            {

            case '1': 
            {
                s.displayDetails();
            }
            break;

            case '2': 
            {
                s.diagnoseSystem();
            } 
            break;

            case '3': 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
                hardDiskSize = keyboard.nextDouble();
                if(hardDiskSize<2) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Hard disk size = Low");
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Hard disk size = Ok");
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter memory size in MB: ");
                memorySize = keyboard.nextInt();
                if(memorySize<128) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Memory Ok = False");
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Memory Ok = True");
                }


            }
            break;

            case '4' : 
            {
                System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();
            }
            break;

            case '5' : break;
            default :  System.out.println("Enter only numbers from 1 - 5");
                       System.out.println();
            }
        } while(choice != '5');




    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem when running above code?

Comment: after changing sizes, it doesnt print the new sizes is what he is saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your switch statement in case 3, you are setting the value of two variables hardDiskSize and memorySize.

when choosing 1 or 2, you are printing s.displayDetails() and s.diagnoseSystem.

s in this case is your "System".

now when looking at case 3, you dont change anything in your "System" directly, but just change values of two variables.

in order to display the new sizes however, those changes would need to happen to your actual "System"

so something like this would do the trick:

```
case '3': 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
        hardDiskSize = keyboard.nextDouble();
        s.setHardDisk(hardDiskSize); //setting the harddisk size in the "System"
        if(hardDiskSize<2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hard disk size = Low");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Hard disk size = Ok");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter memory size in MB: ");
        memorySize = keyboard.nextInt();
        s.setMemory(memorySize); //setting the new memory size within the "system"
        if(memorySize<128) 
        {
            System.out.println("Memory Ok = False");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Memory Ok = True");
        }
    }
```

or if you only want to change the sizes if those if conditions are met:

```
case '3': 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
        hardDiskSize = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(hardDiskSize<2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hard disk size = Low");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Hard disk size = Ok");
            s.setHardDisk(hardDiskSize); //setting the harddisk size in the "System" if it is ok
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter memory size in MB: ");
        memorySize = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(memorySize<128) 
        {
            System.out.println("Memory Ok = False");
        }

        else 
        {
            s.setMemory(memorySize); //setting the new memory size within the "system" if it is ok
            System.out.println("Memory Ok = True");
        }
    }
```